# CSS animation not happening when chrome auto-completes password

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a simple website, and now I'm working on the login page. It looks like this (run in full page, otherwise some parts miss):

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  height:100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}


input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active,
input:-webkit-autofill:valid {
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px #2196F3 inset;
 -webkit-text-fill-color: white !important;
 }

.msg {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 300px;
  line-height: 28px;
  min-height: 28px;
  background-color: #ffc107;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
}

.spacer {
 font-size: 15px;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 word-wrap: break-word;
 width: 90%;
 max-width: 300px;
 line-height: 28px;
 min-height: 28px;
 border-radius: 2px;
 color: white;
 margin-top: 2em;
 margin-bottom: 3em;
}

form {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: -100px;
  text-align: center;
  animation: swipein 0.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes swipein {
  from{top:30%;opacity: .8}
  to{top:20%;opacity: 1}
}

input, button {
  font-family: "Roboto", "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  color: white;
}

.group { 
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative; 
  margin-bottom: 20px; 
}
.group:nth-of-type(1){
  margin-top: 15%;
}


input {
  font-size:21px;
  padding:10px 10px 10px 5px;
  display:block;
  width:250px;
  border:none;
  border-bottom:1px solid white;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
}
input:focus   { outline:none; }

label      {
  color: white; 
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:normal;
  position:absolute;
  pointer-events:none;
  left:5px;
  top:10px;
  transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -moz-transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -webkit-transition:0.2s ease all;
}

input:focus ~ label, input:valid ~ label   {
  top:-20px;
  font-size:14px;
  color: white ;
}

.bar  { position:relative; display:block; width:265px; }
.bar:before, .bar:after  {
  content:'';
  height:2px; 
  width:0;
  bottom:1px; 
  position:absolute;
  background:white; 
  transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -moz-transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -webkit-transition:0.2s ease all;
}
.bar:before {
  left:50%;
}
.bar:after {
  right:50%; 
}

input:focus ~ .bar:before, input:focus ~ .bar:after {
  width:50%;
}

li {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 10px;
}

a {
 color: white;
 padding: 10px;
}


button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  padding: 12px 65px 12px 65px;
  background-color: white;
  color: #2196F3;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 18px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px){
  logo {
    top: 15%;
  }
  .logo span {
    font-size: 2em;
  }
  .logo h2 {
    font-size: 2.7em;
  }
  .group:nth-of-type(1){
    margin-top: 25%;
  }
  form {
    width: 750px;
    top: 20%;
    left: calc(50% - 375px);
  }
  input{
    width:350px;
  }
  .bar { 
    width:365px; 
  }
}
```

```html
    <title>connerdassen.ddns.net</title>
    
  
 <script>
  function test() {
   var button = document.getElementById('button');
   button.click();
   alert('Click event simulated!');
  }
 </script>
 
 

  <body id='body'>
    <form id="form" method="POST" action="http://connerdassen.ddns.net/login.php">
        <p>
        </p><div class="group">      
          <input id='input' type="text" name="uid" required="">
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <label>Username</label>
        </div><p>
        </p><div class="group">      
          <input id='input' type="password" name="pwd" required="">
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <label>Password</label>
   <li><a href='/signup'>Sign up</a></li> 
   <button>Log In</button>
  </div><br>
  </form>
  
  <script>
      if((window.location.href).indexOf('?') != -1) {
        var afterURL = (window.location.href).substr((window.location.href).indexOf('?') + 1);
        var msg = (afterURL.split('msg='))[1];
        msg = decodeURIComponent(msg);
      }

      if(typeof msg !== "undefined" && msg !== "undefined" && msg !== ""){
        var form = document.getElementById("form");
        var oldForm = form.innerHTML;
        form.innerHTML = '<div class="spacer"></div><div class="msg"><span>' + msg + '</span></div>' + oldForm;
      }
   
    </script>
</body>
```

As you see the labels 'Username' and 'Password' are animated up when selecting the input. But when google chrome auto-fills them, the username is automatically animated upwards, but the password label stays, as you can see [here](https://imgur.com/a/HhF9v). After clicking any key on the keyboard/ mouse, the label is animated up immediately. I want the password to go up immediately. How would I do this?

Comment: when the document is ready you can check all inputs if they are already filled and trigger a change event.

Comment: @Sysix and how would I do that?